# autcomplete jquery-ui , parameter doesn't recognized as string

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

my parameter in autocomplete function isn't recognized in jquery-ui when i do a console.log, i see an autocomplete-url and [Object object] after
that's my code :
`import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite';
import { autocomplete, getAlgoliaResults } from '@algolia/autocomplete-js';

const searchClient = algoliasearch(
'latency',
'6be0576ff61c053d5f9a3225e2a90f76'
);
$(document).ready(function() {

```
$("#search").each(function () {
    var autocompleteUrl = $(this).attr('autocomplete-url');
    console.log('autocomplete vaut ' + autocompleteUrl);
    $("#search").autocomplete({hint: false}, {
            source: function(query,cb){
                $.ajax({
                    url: autocompleteUrl
                }).then(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
                console.log(autocompleteUrl+query);
            },
        },
    )
});
```

});

and my screenshot:
[image]

`

i try have my response of my request .

Comment: Can you share the HTML that contains the `input#search` ?

Comment: `<div class="h-100 d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="flex col-4"></div>
    <div id="autocomplete" class="col-5"><input  id="search" autocomplete-url="https://geo.api.gouv.fr/regions?nom=" class="flex" type="text"><button class="btn-primary">Chercher</button></div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
</div>`

Comment: Do you have this working now?

Comment: now , it's work but it's not display under the input bar

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery UI Autocomplete documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) specifies that the `source` value, when a function, will be called with two arguments: `request` and `response`. `request` is an object that contains the `term`, as you have identified. `response` is a callback that will be called with the array of values you want to have appear in the dropdown.

Assuming our API response is an array of objects, each contains a `nom` property, we will need to map that into an array of strings (or, optionally, an array of objects with `label` and `value` properties) and invoke the `response` callback, passing it the mapped values.

```
$("#search").autocomplete({ hint: false }, {
  source: function(request, response) {
    console.log(request.term);
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: autocompleteUrl + request.term
    })
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data[0].nom);
        response(data.map(item => item.nom));
      });
  },
  delay: 500,
  minLength: 2
});
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253100/discussion-on-answer-by-76484-autcomplete-jquery-ui-parameter-doesnt-recogniz); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

the code just display the result in the console, not under the input search bar.It's not query but query.term , we can know it when we dsiplay the object query.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#search").each(function () {
        var autocompleteUrl = $(this).attr('autocomplete-url');
        console.log('autocomplete vaut ' + autocompleteUrl);
        $("#search").autocomplete({hint: false}, {
            source: function(query) {
                console.log(query.term);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: autocompleteUrl + query.term}).then(function(data){
                        console.log(data[0].nom);
                })},
            select: function (event, ui){
                 event.preventDefault();
                 console.log(ui)
                 $(event.target).val(ui);
                 $('#search').html(ui);
             },
            delay: 500,
            minLength: 2,

        });
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

my response is brut data , this is  the image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

so , i resume for the viewers:

- you have to add the jquery-ui.css
  -remove the appendTo attribute
- use response method to return results.
  And is not necessary to use JSON data .In this case the api return brut data
  so , the code is :

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$("#search").each(function () {
    var autocompleteUrl = $(this).attr('autocomplete-url');
    console.log('autocomplete vaut ' + autocompleteUrl);
    $("#search").autocomplete({hint: false}, {
        source: function (query, response) {
                let donnees ;
            /*  $.getJSON(
                  autocompleteUrl + query.term,
                  function (data) {
                      response(data);
                  });*/
            console.log(query.term);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                cache: false,
                url: autocompleteUrl + query.term + '&fields=departement&boost=population&limit=5' }).then(function (result) {
                noms=JSON.stringify(result);

                    response($.map(result, function(item){
                        console.log(item.nom);
                        return item.nom ;

                    }),
                    );
                });
        },

          select: function (event, ui){
               event.preventDefault();
              console.log(ui);
               $(event.target).val(ui.item.value);
                return false ;
           },
          focus:function( event, ui ) {
            console.log(ui);
          $( "#search" ).val( ui.item.value);
          return false;
      },
        delay: 500,
        minLength: 2,
    });
})
```

})